# ContextMenu Binding from a TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple task to bind a context menu to items in a TreeView. If I define the context menu statically no problem. But if I want to bind the context menu to my "root" data context things start to break. So far I was not able to find a correct way to bind my Context menu to the original DataContext the TreeView uses. 
What binding magic is need to get this working?
This Binding does not work:

```
  <MenuItem Name="Name" Header="{Binding Path=DataContext.ContextMenuName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}" />
```

Below is the full sample:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons, Mode=OneTime}" Name="cTree">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
                        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Name="Name" Header="{Binding Path=DataContext.ContextMenuName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}" />
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </TextBox.ContextMenu>
                    </TextBox>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>



public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string[] Persons
    {
        get { return new string[] { "Alois", "Kraus", "Joe", "xxxx" }; }
    }

    public string ContextMenuName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        ContextMenuName = "This is the data bound menu name";
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Basically I want to bind the property ContextMenuName (actually a command in my ViewModel) of the main form. Since the TreeView is rebinding its childs to the Persons (strings to keep it simple) I cannot get the root DataContext out of it. So far I was never able to find any Ancestor (TreeView or MainWindow) which should solve the issue? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ContextMenu` ***doesn't lie in same visual tree*** as that of control on which it is applied. So `FindAncestor` won't be able to get to TreeView since it is not ancestor of ContextMenu.

Also `ElementName` won't work here since it also need two controls to be in same Visual tree.

You can use [x:Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allows to bind even if they don't lie in same visual tree:

```
<MenuItem Name="Name" 
          Header="{Binding Path=DataContext.ContextMenuName,
                           Source={x:Reference cTree}}" />
```

Comment: That did the trick! I have read many SO questions about databinding but Source and Reference did never show up during my search. Thanks a lot that one has cost me quite some time.

Comment: Probably 4-6 hours of searching before you solved my problem.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding via `ElementName=cTree` instead of `RelativeSource={...}`?